# Stop Ubuntu Software from wiping out Python version and venv

Tags: python, software-center

Less than two hours ago, the software updater wiped out my Python 3.11.2 *manual* install, and the venv I was using right along with it. I also have a Poetry lock file, but that didn't stop the software downloader. I have 2.7, 3.9, 3.10 on this computer. They were not wiped out.

- How do I keep the software downloader from changing my versions?!
- Is it *supposed* to do this, when having multiple Python versions is so
  common?
- Is putting it in a different location good enough?
- Suggestions as to which other location?

Thanks.

Comment: Explain how you installed those? On a production server I have 4 pythons independent of the OS -all- in /opt/. Those never get touched by apt.

Answer (score 1):

If you put files in a directory that is used by apt (or snap or ANY package manager), your files are in danger of being manipulated, mangled, or removed by the package manager without warning. You may also encounter package manager errors if it discovers unexpected files.

- Industrial robots usually have clear safely lines marked around them, showing where a human is at risk of getting clobbered. Similarly, stay out of directories where apt, snap, and other package managers are working to avoid getting your software clobbered.

There are locations where package managers are not supposed to go, and that's where your *manual* installs should go. The most common are `/usr/local/` and `~/.local/`. The former is in the default $PATH on Ubuntu systems, so installed software should be findable.